# Results from Batched QR function in Cublas

Tags: cuda, cublas

I used `cublasDgeqrfBatched`in Cublas to make QR decompostion of many small matrices.
As an example, I took a `4x4` matrix `A`:

```
 A=  2     9     8     9
    10     2    10    10
    10     5     7     7
     5    10     1     8
```

The outputs from `cublasDgeqrfBatched` are `Array[1]`for `batchsize=1`

```
Array=-15.1658    0.5243    0.4660    0.5243
      -13.7151   10.7655    0.0496    0.1148
      -12.1326    7.7656    3.9365    0.4519
      -11.8688   -0.2585    5.3365    4.5371
```

And `Tauarray`:

```
Tauarray[4]=1.1319
            1.9692
            1.6609
            0.0000
```

The lower part of Array refers to R (in column major storage). This was checked by Matlab as:

```
`[Q,R]=qr(A')` gives:
    R =

  -15.1658  -13.7151  -12.1326  -11.8688 
         0   10.7655    7.7656   -0.2585 
         0         0    3.9365    5.3365 
         0         0         0    4.5371
```

And:

```
   Q =

   -0.1319    0.7609    0.6329    0.0560
   -0.5934   -0.5703    0.5661   -0.0467
   -0.5275    0.2569   -0.3543   -0.7282
   -0.5934    0.1729   -0.3918    0.6815
```

To find `Q`, it is mentioned in the documentation that:

```
Q[j] = H[j][1] H[j][2] . . . H[j](k), where k = min(m,n).
Each H[j][i] has the form
H[j][i] = I - tau[j] * v * v'
where tau[j] is a real scalar, and v is a real vector with
v(1:i-1) = 0 and v(i) = 1; v(i+1:m) is stored on exit in Aarray[j][i+1:m,i],
and tau in TauArray[j][i]
```

So for `H1`, I did:

```
v1=[1; Array(1,2); Array(1,3); Array(1,4)]
v1=[1;  0.5243;  0.4660;   0.5243]

H1=eye(4)-tau(1)*v1*v1'

 H1 =

   -0.1319   -0.5935   -0.5275   -0.5935
   -0.5935    0.6889   -0.2766   -0.3111
   -0.5275   -0.2766    0.7542   -0.2766
   -0.5935   -0.3111   -0.2766    0.6889
```

But for `H2`, I tried:

```
v2=[0; 1; -0.2766;  -0.3111]
H2=eye(4)-tau(1)*v2*v2'
```

But couldn't find a correct result. 
I'm a beginner in Cuda and in Cublas. Could you help me please find `Q`
Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{double h_A[4*4]={2,     9,     8,     9,
                    10,     2,    10,    10,
                    10,     5,     7,     7,
                     5,    10,     1,     8};

    int batch_count = 2;
    int m=4;
    int n=4;
    int ltau=4;//ltau = max(1,min(m,n))

    double **Aarray, **Tauarray;

    Aarray  = (double**)malloc(batch_count*sizeof(double*));


    Tauarray = (double**)malloc(batch_count*sizeof(double*));

    for(int i=0; i<batch_count; i++) {
        Aarray[i] = (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
       Tauarray[i] = (double*)malloc(ltau*sizeof(double));
}



 // Create host pointer array to device matrix storage
    double **d_Aarray, **d_Tauarray, **h_d_Array, **h_d_Tauarray;
    h_d_Array = (double**)malloc(batch_count*sizeof(double*));
    h_d_Tauarray = (double**)malloc(batch_count*sizeof(double*));

    for(int i=0; i<batch_count; i++) {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&h_d_Array[i], m*n*sizeof(double));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&h_d_Tauarray[i], ltau*sizeof(double));
    }

    // Copy the host array of device pointers to the device
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Aarray, batch_count*sizeof(double*));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Tauarray, batch_count*sizeof(double*));

    cudaMemcpy(d_Aarray, h_d_Array, batch_count*sizeof(double*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_Tauarray, h_d_Tauarray, batch_count*sizeof(double*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int tmp;
    //fill Array
    int index;
     for(int k=0; k<batch_count; k++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                index = j*n + i;
                  (Aarray[k])[index] =h_A[index];

            } // i   
        } // j
    } // k
 // Create cublas instance
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    cublasStatus_t stat;

    // Set input matrices on device
    for(int i=0; i<batch_count; i++) {
        cublascall(cublasSetMatrix(m, n, sizeof(double), Aarray[i], m, h_d_Array[i], m));
        cublascall(cublasSetVector(ltau, sizeof(double), Tauarray[i], 1, h_d_Tauarray[i], 1));
    }

    int info;
    int lda=m;
    stat=cublasDgeqrfBatched(handle, m,n, d_Aarray,lda,d_Tauarray,&info,2);
    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
    printf("\n cublasDgeqrfBatched failed");

    // Retrieve result matrix from device
    for(int i=0; i<batch_count; i++)
        {cublascall( cublasGetMatrix(m, n, sizeof(double), h_d_Array[i], m, Aarray[i], m));
         cublascall(cublasGetVector(ltau, sizeof(double),h_d_Tauarray[i], 1, Tauarray[i], 1));
    }
// Clean up resources

    for(int i=0; i<batch_count; i++) {
        free(Aarray[i]);

        cudaFree(h_d_Array[i]);
        cudaFree(h_d_Tauarray[i]);

    }

    free(Aarray);

    free(h_d_Array);
    free(h_d_Tauarray);

    cudaFree(d_Aarray);
    cudaFree(d_Tauarray);

   cublascall( cublasDestroy(handle));

}
```

Comment: Always post a complete, minimal example code.

Comment: I edited my post and added my code

Comment: Since the matrix R is correct, I think that there is no problem in the code but rather in how to obtain Q

Comment: Despite giving us code to look at, you haven't actually shown or explained how you are displaying the result matrix or calculating the Q matrix form the householder reflections. Are you certain you do not just have a column major versus row major ordering problem?

Comment: I haven't calculated Q yet. I just printed `Aarray`and `Tauarray`after performing `cublasGetMatrix`. I want to simulate with Matlab how to calculate Q to implement it later in my code because I need both `R`and `Q`. Concerning the column major storage, I entered the Matrix `A`in my cuda program and its transposed form in Matlab and I want to find the same result.

Comment: Yes, but the *output* from cublas is also in column major. Are you sure you have put it into matlab in the correct order? I'm not going to write extra code for what you posted and then run it just to work out what you have done. Help us help you......

Answer (score 1):

Increment tau for each H. For example for H1 use Tau(1) for H2 use Tau(2) etc